# Unescaping of data in JS

Tags: javascript, escaping

Say i got a variable,

```
var s = "\"\\\"abc\\\"\"";
```

which is unescaped to `"\"abc\""` when i display in the browser.

But i need it to be further unescaped to the actual value "abc".

Answer (score 0):

You can, but probably shouldn't, call `eval`:

```
s = eval(s);
```

However, this is extremely dangerous.

For a safer solution, please provide more detail.

Comment: I'm calling a service which returns me the raw values of a form component in JSON. The value to be displayed in actually "abc" (with quotes), but the JSON returned is "\"\\\"abc\\\"\"". Is the service suppose to return "\"abc\"" instead?

var returned = {
  value: "\"\\\"abc\\\"\""
}